# How to replace variable in tinymce using template_replace_values?

Tags: javascript, replace, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to replace value using `template_replace_values` in tinymce. I have added `<p>Name: {$username}, StaffID: {$staffid}</p>` in textarea and `template_replace_values:{username: "Jack Black",staffid: "991234"}` in tinymce.init. When I run the code, the variable not replaced with value. It still showing the variable.

```js
// Initialize TinyMCE
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea", // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "template",
  template_replace_values: 
  {
    username: "Jack Black",
    staffid: "991234"
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Preview TinyMCE variable plugin</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <textarea rows="18">
   <p>Name: {$username}, StaffID: {$staffid}</p>
 </textarea>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I follow the example shown in [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/template/#template_replace_values).Is the variable declaration `{$staffid}` with braces and dollar sign incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template_replace_values` option happens when you insert content into the editor via a template (using the `template` plugin).  It does not perform any sort of global find/replace of values as the editor is first initialized.

In your example above you have some "default" content in the `textarea` that will be loaded into the editor as it is initialized.  As that content is not inserted via a template the setting you reference won't impact the content.

I have created a fiddle that shows how the `template` plugin works:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/1khaab

If you use the `Insert` menu and select `Insert template...` you will see that the HTML of the template is inserted and the replacement takes place.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for explanation and example.